# Will grant_type=client_credentials now work with Using Basic Authentication with Named Credentials?

Tags: oauth, namedcredentials

Lots of questions over the years about using the grant_type=client_credentials version of oAuth with Named Credentials, and how it isn't really supported. I have a customer who wants to use that option, so here we are again. But now we have the new option of [External Credentials with NC](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_named_creds_and_ext_creds.htm&type=5), and with that, the ability to [Using Basic Authentication with Named Credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_custom_headers_basic_auth.htm&type=5), I figured it should be possible.

But as far as I can tell, although I can now pass in the credentials in the header via Basic Auth, I also need to pass in 'grant_type=client_credentials' in the body of the request. And I don't see that as an option anywhere? So before I go down some other route, is that an option I am missing in the docs?

Comment: External Creds don't change what NC can do out of the box, `client_credentials`  is still unsupported for callouts via NC: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdYlxUAF/name-credentials-to-support-client-id-authentication . Basic Auth has been supported by NC since its inception.

Comment: Thanks for confirming - I suspect SFDC will never support it, since they see it as less secure than the other options